# How to configure branch protection rules as code in GitHub?

Tags: github, github-actions

Id like to configure my branch protection rules as code, perhaps even more GitHub Settings, is there any way to do so.

Comment: like the [GitHub Terraform Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs)?